# MPI Program Error- Why i get allways this exit code 0xc0000005?

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi, hpc

I have problems with my MPI Code in C. My program crashes sometimes and i get this exit code:

```
job aborted:
[ranks] message

[0] process exited without calling finalize

[1-2] terminated

---- error analysis -----

[0] on LOLANODE1011
project.exe ended prematurely and may have crashed. exit code 0xc0000005

---- error analysis -----
```

Sometimes it works i dont know why :(
The code is for a job on a cluster. But it only works in commandline.
I think it should be something with the arrays or Send and Receive, but Im not sure....

Main:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
double *array_distances;
int array_points[2];
int process_count;
int rank;

int city2;
int start_point;
int end_point;

double start_time;
double end_time;
double duration;


//MPI Initiate
MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &process_count);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
start_time = MPI_Wtime();


struct local_stack local_work;
struct route best_route;
int num_cities;
double *distance;
char city_names[MAX_CITIES][MAX_CITY_NAME_LENGTH];
int city;

double coord[MAX_CITIES][2];


if (argc == 2) {
    num_cities = atoi(argv[1]);
}
else {
    num_cities = 0;
}

// Initiate best route in process 0
if (rank == 0) {
    init_best_route(&best_route);
}

// Calculate start and endpoint for the current process
if (num_cities==0) {
    num_cities = 15;
}
int rest = num_cities % process_count;

if (rest == 0) {
    start_point = (num_cities / process_count)* rank;
    end_point = (num_cities / process_count)* (rank + 1);
}
else
{
    start_point = ((num_cities - rest) / process_count)* rank;
    end_point = ((num_cities - rest) / process_count)* (rank + 1);
    if (rank == (process_count - 1)) {
        end_point += rest;
    }
}

// Calculate distances between the cities
populate_distance_matrix(process_count, rank, &distance, &num_cities, city_names, start_point, 
end_point);

// current process (not process 0!) sends the calculated distances and the start- and endpoint to 
process 0
if (rank > 0) {
    int array_size = num_cities * (end_point - start_point);
    array_distances = malloc(sizeof(double) * array_size);

    //send start- and endpoint
    array_points[0] = start_point;
    array_points[1] = end_point;
    MPI_Request req2;
    MPI_Isend(&array_points, 2, MPI_INT, 0, rank, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &req2);

    //put distances in array
    int i = 0;
    for (start_point; start_point < end_point; start_point++) {
        for (city2 = 0; city2 < num_cities; city2++) {
            array_distances[i] = *(distance + start_point * num_cities + city2);
            i++;
        }
    }

    //send distances to process 0
    MPI_Request req;
    MPI_Isend(array_distances, array_size, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, rank+1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &req);
    MPI_Wait(&req, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);

}

//process 0 receives all distances and start- and endpoint
if (rank == 0) {
    for (int i = 1; i < process_count; i++) {
        //receive start- and endpoint
        MPI_Recv(&array_points, 2, MPI_INT, i, i, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
        start_point = array_points[0];
        end_point = array_points[1];

        //receive distances
        int count = 0;
        int size;
        MPI_Status status;
        // Wait for a message 
        MPI_Probe(i, i + 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        // Find out the number of elements in the message -> size goes to "size"
        MPI_Get_count(&status, MPI_DOUBLE, &size);
        //receive
        MPI_Recv(array_distances, size, MPI_DOUBLE, i, i + 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
        // save distances in memory
        for (start_point; start_point < end_point; start_point++) {
            for (city2 = 0; city2 < num_cities; city2++) {
                *(distance + start_point * num_cities + city2) = array_distances[count];
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
}
free(array_distances);
// process 0: search for the best route
if (rank == 0) {
    init_stack(&local_work);
    push_first_work_local(&local_work, num_cities);
    expand_top_route(&local_work, &num_cities, &best_route, distance);
        //printf("[%d] Let's start the fun!\n", );fflush(stdout);
    while (!empty(&local_work)) {
        //printf("[%d][w %d] Has work\n", , );fflush(stdout);
        expand_top_route(&local_work, &num_cities, &best_route, distance);
        /*
        if ( % 100 == 0) {
            printf("[%d] Finished %dth loop iteration\n", , );
        }
        */
    }

    //printf("[%d][w %d] I am out\n", ,  - 1);fflush(stdout);

    free(distance);

    /*printf("==========================\n");
    printf("# cities: %d\n", num_cities);
    printf("==========================\n");
    print_route(best_route, "Best route:\n");
    for (city = 0; city < num_cities; city++) {
        printf("%2d\tCity %2d/%c\t%s\n", city, best_route.route[city],
            best_route.route[city] + 48, city_names[best_route.route[city]]);
    }*/
}
// MPI show duration
end_time = MPI_Wtime();

if (rank == 0) {
    duration = end_time - start_time;
    /*printf("==========================\n");
    printf("\\\\     //\n");
    printf(" \\\\   //\n");
    printf("  \\\\_// Duration: %f\n", duration);*/


    fprintf(stderr, "%f,%f", duration, best_route.length);
    for (int index = 0; index < num_cities; index++) {

        fprintf(stderr, "%2d,", best_route.route[index]);

    }
    printf("%d, %d, %f\n", process_count, num_cities, duration);
}









MPI_Finalize();

return 0;
}
```

If someone could help me it would be nice :)

Comment: you never `MPI_Wait(&req2)` (and you should use blocking `MPI_Send()` instead. you also never allocate `array_distances` on rank `0`.

Comment: The debugger will tell you _wher_ the crash happens, and this information might help you (and us) to find the bug.

Comment: That error code means you have issues with memory management (segmentation faults, free of an already freed pointer, ... )

Comment: thanks it worked for me to allocate array_distances on rank 0 :)

Comment: if you call `MPI_Isend()` but never `MPI_Wait()` before exiting the block in which the send buffer is declared, then consider yourself lucky if the program produces the expected result.